# Compiler Error: Failed to read file attributes for .../Resources/Images.xcassets

Tags: xamarin.ios

I recently updated to the latest version of `XCode` and `Xamarin` `Xamarin.iOS 10.0.0.1 (29910bb)` running `Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3`. Both my Mac (build machine) and PC are fully up to date. Now that i have update i am no longer able to compile/build for anything but the simulator.

Compiler Error.

> ```
> > C:\Program Files
> > (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1028,3): error :
> > Failed to read file attributes for
> > "/Users/mod/Library/Caches/Xamarin/Resources/Images.xcassets"
> ```

As a test i copied the solutions file over to the build machine and with no modifications it compiles and runs any of the targets.

I have also tried deleting the builds directory on the build machine and no help.

Anyone know what the work around is for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across is this issue and what seems to possibly be related to on [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77718/failed-to-read-file-attributes-for-users-resources-media-xcassets-no-such-file-or-directory). The thing I found in my case was related to image assets within a library I was trying to use. I was able to remove the image assets and relocate to main project and that seemed to resolve the build issue.

This problem, like you have found is very recent. For what's it worth, I have also found that command line tools have numerous issues as they seem to lag behind the GUI provided in either Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/224326/#Comment_224326) I had to delete the folder `~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds` on the Mac used for the builds.

After a rebuild it worked again.